# Como acessar uma instância EC2, após perder a Key Pair?

Tags: amazon-aws

Perdi a minha Key Pair de acesso a um servidor EC2, como faço para recuperá-la?

Há alguma maneira de gerar uma nova Key Pair e adicionar a uma instância já existente?

Comment: Perdeu a "Key Pair" que estava aonde? Na máquina local?

Comment: @DiegoSouza Sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o usuário perde o Key Pair, e não havia preparado anteriormente nenhuma outra forma de acesso à sua instância, realmente não há o que fazer -- **o acesso está perdido**! (a não ser em casos especiais, veja mais à frente)

Isso ocorre pois a AWS não tem como acessar a sua instância -- você era o único que possuía a chave. **A chave é instalada na instância por ela própria**, durante o primeiro processo de boot -- a AWS não tem como se conectar na sua instância e trocar a chave para você. Nos boots subsequentes, esse processo não executa, então não adianta gerar nova chave pelo console, com novo nome ou mesmo nome, ou qualquer coisa assim.

Dependendo das circunstâncias específicas, é possível você fazer um processo bem manual e trabalhoso para ganhar acesso novamente à sua instância. Esse processo só se aplica a instâncias que usam EBS como root device, e além disso todo o conteúdo gravado nos volumes efêmeros (*instance store*) será perdido.

Da documentação da AWS:

> Amazon EC2 doesn't keep a copy of your private key; therefore, if you lose your private key, there is no way to recover it. If you lose the private key for an instance store-backed instance, you can't access the instance; you should terminate the instance and launch another instance using a new key pair. If you lose the private key for an EBS-backed instance, you can regain access to your instance.

**Fonte e mais informações sobre o processo de recuperação: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html**

Answer (score 2):

Um outro modo de resolver isso seria:

1. Pare a instância com o Key Pair perdido (Use o **Stop**, não **Terminate**, hein?)
2. Crie uma nova instância com mesmo SO e região da instância sem Key Pair
3. Gerar um novo **Key Pair**
4. Pare a instância que acabou de criar
5. Desconectar o disco EBS padrão da instância nova
6. Conectar o disco da máquina antiga à instância nova. Certifique que estará como device `/dev/sda1`
7. Religue a nova instância.

Você tem a opção de ou usar o Volume EBS que foi criado junto com a instância nova ou conecta-lo novamente à instância como um disco extra, que poderia servir como backup por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Temos então 2 possibilidades:

- Gerar localmente o par de chaves com o comando **ssh-keygen** (para sistemas derivados do Unix) e importar a chave pública pelo botão **Import Key Pair**.
- Gerar um novo par de chaves através do botão **Create Key Pair**. Aí logo em seguida a Amazon envia a chave privada para você salvar.

Tudo isso fica no [Console do EC2](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/), menu **Network & Security > Key Pairs**.

Comment: Mas como fazer para atribuir essa chave a uma instância EC2 já existente?

Comment: Ao adicionar pelo painel do AWS EC2, automaticamente a chave será inserida no seu sistema da instância. Faça o teste, logo após inserir você já conseguirá logar.

Comment: Não consigo. `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Tem certeza que está utilizando as chaves corretas? (caso possua vários pares). A chave que você informou no Console AWS é a pública? A privada fica somente com você.

Comment: -1: não há como a AWS substituir, numa instância já criada, um Key Pair. Apenas em alguns casos, e com diversas perdas, existe um processo manual bastante complicado que o usuário tem que fazer para ganhar acesso à sua instância. Mais informações em minha resposta.

Comment: @BrunoReis realmente não tem como recuperar, já aconteceu comigo e eu tive que criar uma nova instância, sorte que era apenas uma instância de teste. Só não entendo essas opções de criar um no `Key Pair` se não tem como usar.

Comment: @Orion: acho que não entendi o que você quer dizer. Na verdade, vc tem sim como usar um Key Pair: o sistema operacional configura o seu acesso com o Key Pair durante o primeiro boot. O que vc quer dizer com "não tem como usar"?

Comment: @BrunoReis vc entendeu errado, eu disse que nao tem como utilizar um novo key pair, nao estou falando do original

Comment: Para usar um novo Key Pair, você faz a mesma coisa: cria uma nova instância e fala para ela usar o novo Key Pair. Acho que o que você quer dizer é justamente o que foi perguntado e respondido nesta página: se você perder o Key Pair, não há como **substituí-lo** (o que, novamente, não significa que não tem como usar um novo). Veja que isso é uma característica importantíssima (e não uma falha) do serviço EC2: se fosse possível a AWS substituir o Key Pair, significaria que a AWS teria acesso ao seu servidor, o que seria uma catástrofe para a segurança, concorda?